# target select by siblings content

Tags: jquery, siblings

i want to target the select boxes by there option title (inside bold tags) the code is dynamically generated the only thing i know that will be constant is **option title:**(inside bold tags) how can i target in jquery

```
<div id="option-264" class="option">
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <b>Board Type:</b><br />
    <select name="option[264]" class="optionChoice">
        <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
        <option value="20">All Mountain </option>
        <option value="21">Straight Jibber </option>
        <option value="22">Bender </option>
        <option value="23">Tripod </option>
     </select>
</div>
<br />
<div id="option-265" class="option">
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <b>Board Size:</b><br />
    <select name="option[265]" class="optionChoice">
        <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
        <option value="17">146                        </option>
        <option value="18">147                        </option>
        <option value="19">149                        </option>
        <option value="24">150                        </option>
        <option value="25">152                        </option>
        <option value="26">153                        </option>
        <option value="27">155                        </option>
        <option value="28">156                        </option>
        <option value="29">157                        </option>
        <option value="30">158                        </option>
        <option value="31">159                        </option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What about using the class `$('.optionChoice')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By title, do you mean Board Size, Board Type etc? Should be able to do it using [:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$(".option:contains('title')").find('select')
```